# docker-compose fails to start with npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, package.json

I built an image from a docker file to run node and copy in a simple node express app which works perfectly. The image builds I can run a container and bash in and the local files are copied. When I use this image in a docker-compose file along with a mongo image the containers build but the node container fails to run with an error is the package.json is missing.

The error returned is

```
report-node exited with code 254
report-node | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
report-node | npm ERR! code ENOENT
report-node | npm ERR! errno -2
report-node | npm ERR! syscall open
report-node | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
report-node | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
report-node | npm ERR! enoent
report-node |
report-node | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
report-node | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-26T10_55_05_562Z-debug.log
report-node exited with code 254
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"  ]
```

Docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: gosmith/node10:latest
    container_name: report-node
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 8080:8080
    command: npm run dev && npm run serve
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27037:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

How has the package.json gone missing?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When your `docker-compose.yml` says

```
volumes:
  - ./:/usr/src/app
```

it hides *everything* that gets done in the Dockerfile and replaces it with the current directory.  If your current directory doesn't have the `package.json` file (maybe you moved everything Docker-related into a subdirectory) it will cause the error you see.

Personally I would just remove these two lines, develop my application locally (without Docker, using the per-project `node_modules` directory for isolation), and only build the Docker image when I'm actually ready to deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

I also face same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and docker-desktop 20.10.16 I changes following:

**Before Solving Problem:**

Dockerfile contain

```
WORKDIR /app
```

And docker-compose.yaml file contains:

```
services:
   backend:
     volumes:
        - ./:/app
```

**After Solving Problem** my files look like

**Dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR /app/project
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  backend:
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/project
```

Comment: Adding additional subfolder worked for me too, but I have no clue why...

Comment: Additional subfolder worked for me as well! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In your case do it like this:
In volumes changes this `- ./:/usr/src/app` for this

```
volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

the `/app` name is this:

```
services:
   app:
```