# package.json not found in Docker container for .NET core application

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I'm currently learning .NET core and I'm working on a Docker image for running my code in. My project is located in the `~/src/Web` where a `docker-compose.yml` file is at the root of the directory structure. This file contains the following code:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    web:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: src/Web/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=localhost
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/localhost.pfx
        volumes:
          - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

My Dockerfile, in the `src/Web` directory, looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS runtime

# Install Node.js 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build

# Install Node.js 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["src/Web/Web.csproj", "src/Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Web/Web.csproj"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "src/Web/Web.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "src/Web/Web.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

FROM runtime  as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

When I build this image, by using `docker-compose up --build` it succeeds. But when whilst running the container I get the following error:

```
web_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
web_1  |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
web_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
web_1  |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {5e5dd257-5689-45a2-b838-01f01d53ec46} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
web_1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
web_1  |       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
web_1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
web_1  |       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
web_1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
web_1  |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
web_1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
web_1  |       Hosting environment: Development
web_1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
web_1  |       Content root path: /app
web_1  | npmfail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
web_1  |       npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1  |
web_1  | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
web_1  |       npm ERR! syscall open
web_1  |       npm ERR! path /app/Presentation/package.json
web_1  |       npm ERR! errno -2
web_1  |       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/Presentation/package.json'
web_1  |
web_1  | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
web_1  |       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1  |       npm ERR! enoent
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
web_1  |       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I don't understand where this is coming from, because when I tried his without Docker, and simply use the same publish command in my command line, the error doesn't appear. I also tried using different versions of Node.js.

How can I run this application within Docker without receiving this error? Also, is this a common way of setting up a development environment for working with .NET core or is `dotnet run watch` only used?

Comment: Check out the answers on this SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod
One even mentions this problem on Docker.  May help.
Also check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679995/docker-npm-err-enoent-enoent

Comment: @raddevus It appeared to be a problem with the volumes section indeed. But I do need it for using the dev ca certificate. Is there any way to by pass it?

Comment: This may help: https://medium.com/@semur.nabiev/how-to-make-docker-compose-volumes-ignore-the-node-modules-directory-99f9ec224561

Comment: @raddevus It worked. Is this the common way to develop though? I don't think it watches file change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @raddevus commented; see the these questions:

- [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17990647/2989034)
- [docker : npm ERR! enoent ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679995/)

Also checkout this [Medium article.](http://%20medium.com/@semur.nabiev/%E2%80%A6)