# Error "enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'" for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Dockerfile for my NodeJS client:

```
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then, I get my client into a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    stdin_open: true
    image: client:latest
    container_name: react-ui
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
    image: server:latest
    container_name: node-api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9901:9901"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - mongo-seed
  
  mongo-seed:
    build: ./mongo-seed
    image: mongo_seed:latest
    container_name: seed
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - default

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-database
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/my_database

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

I then build my client using the command:
`docker-compose build client`

And save that build as a tarball file:
`docker save -o client_image.tar client:latest`

Next I load the tarball into docker:
`docker load -i client_image.tar`

To finally run it with:
`docker-compose up`

However, everytime I do I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-12-19T02_18_10_854Z-debug-0.log
```

Looking at the files of my client in the files explorer in Docker Desktop, I can see that I indeed have a `package.json` in my 'app' folder.

For context, my Dockerfile is in the same directory that my client's `package.json`, inside the 'client' folder that's at the root of my project. My `docker-compose.yml` file is also in the root of the project.
What could be happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: /app would be from the root of the filesystem no? Can you try ./app?

Comment: @Phix No, it says that `WORKDIR` paths must be absolute

Comment: Why is there an asterisk after package in this line `COPY package*.json .`?

Comment: @Geshode That way the `package-lock.json` also gets copied without having to write an explicit line for it

Comment: Which service is generating those logs? Could you please [edit] your question with the actual output from `docker compose up` which typically prefixes each line with the service name

Comment: FYI you should be using `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`. There's also absolutely no need to `save` and `load` images

Comment: The `volumes:` blocks in the `frontend` and `backend` containers hide all of the source code in their image, including the `package.json` files, and I'd recommend deleting those.  Also see [docker-compose fails to start with npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884565/docker-compose-fails-to-start-with-npm-err-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-direc) if that is in fact your problem.